# How to combine two partitions into one?

Tags: partition

I have an USB disk. When I insert it into my PC, the USB interface displays two partition:`sdb1` and `sdb4`.

```
root@debian:~# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 149.1 GiB, 160041885696 bytes, 312581808 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xa350a350

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         2048    206847    204800  100M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          208894 312580095 312371202  149G  f W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5       240011264 306278399  66267136 31.6G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda6       306280448 312580095   6299648    3G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda7          208896  80285695  80076800 38.2G 83 Linux
/dev/sda8        80287744 163878911  83591168 39.9G 83 Linux
/dev/sda9       163880960 240011263  76130304 36.3G  b W95 FAT32

Partition table entries are not in disk order.
Disk /dev/sdb: 14.6 GiB, 15610576896 bytes, 30489408 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xc3072e18

Device     Boot    Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *       16128 30489407 30473280 14.5G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/sdb4       11580256 13523807  1943552  949M  0 Empty
```

**How to combine `sdb1` and `sdb4` into  `sdb` ?**
It is strange that it is displayed as **sdb**, only **sdb1** can be detected, the sdb4 can't be detected in gparted.

[image]
Let us get the mbr in my sdb with the command

```
dd if=/dev/sdb of=/home/mbr.img bs=512 count=1
```

Output the mbr.img with xxd.

```
xxd  /home/mbr.img
```

**How to fix the mbr?**

[image]

Comment: Do you have data you want/need to preserve here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why doesn't the whole space equal to all the sub partition?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/217162/why-doesnt-the-whole-space-equal-to-all-the-sub-partition)

Comment: `/dev/sdb4` actually overlaps `/dev/sdb1`, as [noticed by jilliagre](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/217167). There's nothing to combine! `sdb4` designates a part of `sdb1`. You need to just remove `sdb4` and not touch `sdb1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you want them to be `/dev/sdb` you'll need to remove the partition table entirely. Maybe the most simple way to do that is just to backup the fs and create it anew.

```sh
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt
tar -C/mnt -cf /tmp/sdb .
sudo umount /mnt
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=1kx1k count=4
sudo mkfs.vfat /dev/sdb
sudo mount /dev/sdb /mnt
tar -C/mnt -xf /tmp/sdb
```

...I think that covers it...

There are other solutions - such as [`fatresize`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/fatresize.1.html) and similar - but they are not as reliable. The real problem is that the FAT filesystem doesn't offer much in the way of intelligence of any kind - whether that be in the way of user-space tools or otherwise. With some research you could figure out how to do this at the byte offset level, but I think you'll find doing the above less hassle.

Answer (score 1):

You need to delete both partition `sdb1` and `sdb4`. So that, it will become single storage device, which you can use it by creating one single partition.

**WARNING: DOING THIS WILL ERASE ALL THE CONTENT OF `SDB1` AND `SDB4`. TAKE A BACKUP IN CASE, THOSE DATA IS VITAL FOR YOU.**