# Why isn't the whole space equal to all the sub partitions?

Tags: partition

```
fdisk  -l 
Partition table entries are not in disk order.

Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xc3072e18

Device     Boot    Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *       16128 30489407 30473280 14.5G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/sdb4       11580256 13523807  1943552  949M  0 Empty
```

sdb1+sdb4=14.5g+949M=15.4g

Why is this : Disk /dev/sdb: `14.6`, 15610576896 bytes, 30489408 sectors, in the fdisk -l info?
It says that the *whole* sdb space is 14.6 GiB. Why is it not the 15.4 GiB?
Why is there about 0.8 GiB space lost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You disk size is 14.538 GiB (30489408 sectors * 512 bytes /1024/1024/1024).

Its partition table is seriously broken as sdb4 is overlapping sdb1.

You should remove sdb4 as soon as possible and in any case, you shouldn't use that fourth partition without a very strong risk of corrupting sdb1 content.